# Changing differentiated variable in a mixed partial derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

What operations do I need to perform the following conversion?

$$
\frac{\partial ^2y}{\partial x\partial z} \mapsto \frac{\partial ^2y}{\partial x\partial t}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be chain rule. From the way you wrote your question, $t$ depends on $z$. So then you should have
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\partial^2 y }{\partial x \partial z} = \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial z}
\end{align*}

Comment: I had thought this might be the correct approach, but something about it seemed too easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the chain rule by changing your z variable to t